# Responsively show different background images on different screen sizes using attr()

Tags: php, html, css, content-management-system, responsive-images

The challenge is that from my CMS (let's say WordPress for arguments sake) I can get different crop sizes of a background image for the banner on my page. These crop sizes are generated for different screen sizes (based on mobile, tablet, laptop, etc).

I would like to be able to render all of the different crop size image URLs as attributes onto the banner DOM element and then in an external CSS document use media queries to pick the correct one to display. The reason I want to do this is that I can write the PHP to dynamically provide the cropped images on different pages.

Something like, HTML:

```
<div style="background-image:url('/img/sm-background-image.jpg')"
   md-background-image="url('/img/md-background-image.jpg')"> ...
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .background-image-style {
        background-image: attr('md-background-image')!important; /* All screen sizes above the smallest and default size */
    }
}
```

So, all screen width of 768px or bigger would display the image provided in `md-background-image` attribute and anything below this size would show the default `background-image` defined in the `style` attribute.

I can see that `attr()` is not supported for `background-image` currently and although there is some future scope for this, I can't use it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved the desired affect by using a combination of the CSS `var()` method and `style` attribute.

My PHP code looks something like this:

```
<div class="banner-image" style="
        --xl-background-image:url('<?php echo $image['sizes']['xl_header_banner_wide']; ?>');
        --lg-background-image:url('<?php echo $image['sizes']['lg_header_banner_wide']; ?>');
        --md-background-image:url('<?php echo $image['sizes']['md_header_banner_wide']; ?>');
        background-image:url('<?php echo $image['sizes']['sm_header_banner_wide']; ?>')">
```

Which renders the HTML:

```
<div class="banner-image" style="
        --xl-background-image:url('/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Products-Header-1489x600.jpg');
        --lg-background-image:url('/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Products-Header-1400x564.jpg');
        --md-background-image:url('/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Products-Header-1024x413.jpg');
        background-image:url('/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Products-Header-768x309.jpg')">
```

I can therefore use the following CSS and media query combination to show the different images based on the client's screen size in my external `style.css` file:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .banner-image {
        background-image: var(--md-background-image)!important;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
    .banner-image {
        background-image: var(--lg-background-image)!important;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px){
    .banner-image {
        background-image: var(--xl-background-image)!important;
    }
}
```

I've checked this on Chrome & FireFox (on Windows) and Safari (on Mac) with developer tools and I haven't noticed any comparability issue.

**Alternative approach:**

Alternatively, I realised as I was writing my above solution, that a less *risky* approach might be to render my styles directly into the page. I guess it's just a questions of compatibility and/or coding standards that separate the two possibilities.

```
<style type="text/css"> 
    @media (min-width: 768px){
        .banner-image {
            background-image: '<?php echo $image['sizes']['md_header_banner_wide']; ?>'!important;
        }
    }
    @media (min-width: 992px){
        .banner-image {
            background-image: url('<?php echo $image['sizes']['lg_header_banner_wide']; ?>')!important;
        }
    }
    @media (min-width: 1200px){
        .banner-image {
            background-image: url('<?php echo $image['sizes']['xl_header_banner_wide']; ?>')!important;
        }
    }
</style>
```