# Serve different image sizes on different screens

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress website running on apache that has a lot of images. What I want to achieve is to serve smaller size images depending on the user's screen. For example, if a user has a 1920x1080 screen then the original images will be served for the user to download. If the screen is something like 400x900 then smaller versions of original images will be served for the user to download. Obviously, the goal is to reduce total bandwidth so that a mobile user has a faster experience without losing any quality. What would be a good approach to that problem?

Comment: You can check the following solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54478352/responsively-show-different-background-images-on-different-screen-sizes-using-at

Comment: Since WordPress 4.4, native responsive images is supported by including srcset and sizes attributes to the image markup it generates. Check out the [WP handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/responsive-images/) for information how to leverage `srcset` to serve smaller images when screen size is smaller